# Is the order of DocuSign envelope statuses guaranteed?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Is the order of DocuSign statuses for a single envelope guaranteed? I am asking in the context of the Docusign for SalesForce managed package.

For example, given that we have only one Signer/ Recipient, will the Delivered status always be sent before Completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The order of the statuses should always be guaranteed and the Delivered Status should be sent before the Completed status as you can see in the definition below that the `Completed` status is reached when the recipients have completed the transaction. On the other hand, the `Delivered` status is reached when the recipients have viewed the envelope but not necessarily signed it:

**Delivered**

```
All recipients have viewed the document(s) in an envelope through the DocuSign signing web site. This is not an email delivery of the documents in an envelope.
```

**Completed**

```
The envelope has been completed by all the recipients.
```

Source : [official documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Status%20and%20Managing%20Group/EnvelopeStatus.htm#Envelope)

Comment: I think qs is for DfS package (not API polling), its type of Connect configured in DS Account, and I am not sure if status is always guaranteed for single recipient. I think there is a small chance that you will receive Completed status instead of Delivered.

Comment: Any official documentation would be appreciated to support that and also to provide reliable information to the user that is inquiring about this.

Comment: It seems we have cases that our SalesForce org is receiving status Completed, before status Delivered. For integrating to Docusign we use the "DocuSign for SalesForce" managed package. As a result, we had to deal with it in our business logic and it is no longer an issue.